# How to delete the repeat values in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

How to delete the repeat values in Visualforce page? I am passing the values in repeat function and every record has a delete button. I need each button to delete that particular record

```
<apex:repeat value="{!delrec}" var="del" >
    <div >
        <apex:outputText  value="{!del.testvalue}">
        </apex:outputText>
    </div>
    <apex:commandButton value="delete" action="{!delete}">
        <apex:param value="{!del.id}" assignTo="{!delrecid}" name="{!del.id}" />
    </apex:commandButton>                       
</apex:repeat>
```

### Controller

```
public string delrecid {get; set;} 
public void delete(){
    testobj__c delobj = [select id, FROM testobj__c where  id=:delrecid];
    delete delobj;
}
```

Comment: Hi, you're going to probably want to [edit] your question and provide some code of what you have so far.

Comment: I had updated my code.could you please see once

Comment: put your visualforce and apex code. After deletion you need rerender the list on VFP.

Comment: In visualforce page what i need to add in rerender?could you please add any example code

Answer (score 1):

After you delete the record, you need to refresh your list (`delrec`), or otherwise remove the value from the list.

```
public Id delRecId { get; set; }

public void delete(){
    Database.delete(delRecId);
    for(Integer index = 0; index < delrec.size(); index++) {
        if(delrec[index].Id == delRecId) {
            delrec.remove(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: above code is not working sfdcfox.

Comment: @user - Could you tell the error message it gave you?  His code assumes you're iterating a list of the records in your controller named "delrec" which should be a List<SObject> (generally with SObject replaced with the specific SObject you're working with here).

Comment: I had used rerender in commandbutton,working now.but first time one record is deleted then after i clicked another delete button its not working.help me on this.i had taken output panel id in rerender.but one time record is deleting second record is not deleting.